# Python catch exception

Tags: python, exception

I am having difficulty working with the two exceptions raised by `lookup(self, key)`. Both are `ValueError` exceptions, yet mean entirely different things. How do I catch these exceptions separately since they are the same type of exception, but require different behavior upon catching them? Thanks!

```
@staticmethod
def _lookup_in_child(child, key):
    if child:
        return child.lookup(key)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Key not in tree: " + repr(key)) 

def lookup(self, key):
    if key is None:
        raise ValueError("None cannot be used as a key")
    if self.key is None:
        raise ValueError("Key not in tree: " + repr(key))

    if key < self.key:
        return self._lookup_in_child(self.left, key)
    elif key > self.key:
        return self._lookup_in_child(self.right, key)
    else:
        return self
```

Comment: Are you the creator of the `lookup` methods?  If you are you can just make two subclasses to `ValueError` and raise them as appropriate.

Comment: It looks as if `LookupError` would be a better choice for the "key not in tree" error.

Comment: nope, I'm working on an assignment that implements a TreeDict using the BinarySearchTree as the container. I have to catch those two exceptions

Comment: `self.key` is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: The first `raise` in your code is wildly misleading. It says "key not in tree" when the truth of `child` was tested.

Comment: You call `self._lookup_in_child` which makes it an instance method, but you've got it declared as a `@staticmethod`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. For instance, couldn't you check if the key is None before calling lookup? Assuming you need to catch the exceptions, the below will do so, and you can then add whatever logic you need based on the specific exception case:

```
try:
    lookup(key)
except ValueError, e:
    if str(e) == 'None cannot be used as a key':
        print 'None case'
    elif str(e).startswith('Key not in tree:'):
        print 'Nonexistent case'
    else:
        print 'Default case'
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementers obviously thought that the two error conditions would be handled the same and that there would be no reason to add something to distinguish them. Contrast this with **`IOError`**, where a numeric code is included. It's hackish and fragile, but you can tell the difference by peeking at the message attribute on the exception object.